# The best way to convert and increase 220v AC to 600v DC(without any oscillation)?

Tags: ac, dc

How can i convert and increase  220v AC to 600v DC(without any oscillation)?

Comment: How much current do you need at 600V? "Without any oscillation" is not possible...how much variation in the voltage can you tolerate?

Comment: @Joe "is not possible" Ok, then with little oscillation. is it possible?

Comment: Yes. You just have to say how much oscillation you can tolerate and at what frequencies.

Comment: The normal transformer+regulator circuit will work, although you'll have to build your own linear regulator and the high voltage will complicate the design. How much current do you need?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "without any oscillation"? Are you just trying to clarify what "DC" means? Do you mean there can be no [ripple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripple_%28electrical%29)? Something else?

Comment: The current should be 0.03a, guys.

Comment: i'm sorry guys, i'm a newbie at electronic.

Comment: "Without any ripple" (as you seem to mean) is impossible (there will always be some noise, which is in effect a ripple). Better state a maximum ripple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't believe you really want no 'oscillation' when you become aware of the consequences.

The only way to do voltage conversion without oscillation is to establish some form of energy transfer to a device that produces DC current/voltage, and then put sufficient of those devices in series. Two examples:

- Use the 220V feed a big light bulb, which shines on a lot of solar panel cells, all put in series.
- Use the 220V to produce heat, which warms the warm side of a huge stack of Peltier elelements or thermocouples. Reserve some energy for a fan to cool the cold side.

Comment: I don't think even those methods eliminate *all* ripple, but just make it *extremely* small.

Comment: The OP didn't mention ripple, he only excluded oscillation. These methods could be fed with DC. IMO they are totally impractical, but sometimes an OP gets what he asked for, which might not be what he wanted. :)

Comment: I see what you mean. I took "oscillation" to mean "ripple".

Comment: Yes, my mean is ripple.